# Exception in thread "Thread-4,9,11,12,13" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java

Пассажиров, прибывших на трех (четырех, пяти) самолетах одновременно, развозят микроавтобусы. Загруженность самолетов – ровно 100 пассажиров. Микроавтобусы имеют вместимость 6 или 7 или 8 пассажиров и едут в 4 разных города. Загрузка микроавтобусов должна быть 100%. Пассажиры уезжают семьями от 1 до 4 человек. Разделять семьи по микроавтобусам нельзя.Я не знаю, как сделать стыковку между маршруткой и самолетом, чтобы узнать, сколько пассажиров заняли свои места в микроавтобусе, чтобы совпадало куда они отправляются по маршруту микроавтобуса.Я не знаю, хорошо ли я справился с этой многопоточностью, возможно, нет, потому что она выдает исключение.

Main class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class loop {
    static String[] cities = {"Kalush", "Kosiv", "Galych", "Kolomiya"};
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<Family> families1 = fillFamily();
    List<Family> families = fillFamily();
    List<Family> families2 = fillFamily();



    Plane plane = new Plane(families, 1);
    Plane plane1 = new Plane(families1, 2);
    Plane plane2 = new Plane(families2, 3);

    List<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<>();
    planes.add(plane);
    planes.add(plane1);
    planes.add(plane2);

    Bus bus = new Bus(6, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus1 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus2 = new Bus(7, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus3 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus4 = new Bus(7, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus5 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus6 = new Bus(6, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus7 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus8 = new Bus(6, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus9 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus10 = new Bus(7, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus11 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus12 = new Bus(7, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus13 = new Bus(8, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);
    Bus bus14 = new Bus(7, cities[new Random().nextInt(4)]);

    Thread thread = new Handler(planes, bus);
    Thread thread1 = new Handler(planes, bus1);
    Thread thread2 = new Handler(planes, bus2);
    Thread thread3 = new Handler(planes, bus3);
    Thread thread4 = new Handler(planes, bus4);
    Thread thread5 = new Handler(planes, bus5);
    Thread thread6 = new Handler(planes, bus6);
    Thread thread7 = new Handler(planes, bus7);
    Thread thread8 = new Handler(planes, bus8);
    Thread thread9 = new Handler(planes, bus9);
    Thread thread10 = new Handler(planes, bus10);
    Thread thread11 = new Handler(planes, bus11);
    Thread thread12 = new Handler(planes, bus12);
    Thread thread13 = new Handler(planes, bus13);
    Thread thread14 = new Handler(planes, bus14);
    thread.start();
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
    thread4.start();
    thread5.start();
    thread6.start();
    thread7.start();
    thread8.start();
    thread9.start();
    thread10.start();
    thread11.start();
    thread12.start();
    thread13.start();
    thread14.start();
    thread.join();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();
    thread5.join();
    thread6.join();
    thread7.join();
    thread8.join();
    thread9.join();
    thread10.join();
    thread11.join();
    thread12.join();
    thread13.join();
    thread14.join();
    System.out.println(planes);
}

    public static List<Family> fillFamily() {
        List<Family> filledFamilies = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 33){
            int Fcount = new Random().nextInt(4) + 1;
            filledFamilies.add(new Family(new Random().ints(58, 122 + 1)
                    .filter(j -> (j <= 57 || j >= 65) && (j <= 90 || j >= 97))
                    .limit(2)
                    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                    .toString(),
                    cities[new Random().nextInt(4)],
                    Fcount));
            count += Fcount;
        }
        return filledFamilies;

    }

}
```

Family class

```
class Family {
    String name; // twoLetters “aa”, “ab”, …, “zz” – for example, up to 100 names
    String travelTo; // 4 cities – “Kalush”, “Kosiv”, “Galych”, “Kolomiya”
    int count;     // family members count, from 1 to 4 members

    public Family(String name, String travelTo, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.travelTo = travelTo;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Family{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", travelTo='" + travelTo + '\'' +
                ", count=" + count +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Plane class

```
class Plane {
    List<Family> families; // exactly 100 family members
    int id;  // exactly 1, 2, 3

    public Plane(List<Family> families, int id) {
        this.families = families;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane{" +
                "families=" + families +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Bus class

```
class Bus {
    int passengersCount; // 6 or 7 or 8
    String driveTo;         // 4 cities
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Bus(int passengersCount, String driveTo) {
        this.passengersCount = passengersCount;
        this.driveTo = driveTo;
    }

    public void landingOnBus(List<Plane> planes){
     if (lock.tryLock()) {
        for (Plane plane: planes) {
            plane.families.forEach(family -> {
                if(family.travelTo.equals(driveTo)){
                    passengersCount--;
                    planes.remove(plane);
                }else if (passengersCount == 0){
                    lock.unlock();
                }else {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println("passengersCount " + passengersCount + " is landing on Bus to: " + driveTo);

    }
}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bus{" +
                "passengersCount=" + passengersCount +
                ", driveTo='" + driveTo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Handler class

```
class Handler extends Thread{
    List<Plane> planes;
    Bus bus;

    public Handler(List<Plane> planes, Bus bus) {
        this.planes = planes;
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        bus.landingOnBus(planes);
    }
}
```

Выводит вот такое:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.llegalMonitorStateException
Exception in thread "Thread-6"
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException java.lang.llegalMonitorStateException
xception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.llegalMonitorStateException
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
passengersCount 8 is landing on Bus to: Kolomiya
passengersCount 8 is landing on Bus to: Kolomiya
passengersCount 6 is landing on Bus to: Kolomiya
passengersCount 7 is landing on Bus to: Kolomiya
passengersCount 8 is landing on Bus to: Kosiv
passengersCount 7 is landing on Bus to: Kalush
passengersCount 8 is landing on Bus to: Kalush
passengersCount 7 is landing on Bus to: Kosiv
```

Comment: *Я не знаю, как сделать стыковку между маршруткой и самолетом, чтобы узнать, сколько пассажиров заняли свои места в микроавтобусе, чтобы совпадало куда они отправляются по маршруту микроавтобуса.* Тебе зачем? всё, они уже прилетели... и какая разница, откуда? представь, что они пешком пришли - что бы поменялось? в общем, просто всех прилетевших вали в одну кучу, и всё.

Comment: как мне тогда микроавтобусы связать с самолетами? у меня 15 объектов микроавтобуса и 3 list самолетов

Comment: Зачем? **Нет между ними никакой связи.** Самолёт прилетел и вывалил пассажиров, и ему пофиг, что с ними будет дальше. Автобус приехал и взял пассажиров из кучи, и ему всё равно, откуда в этой куче пассажир появился, каким рейсом прилетел и вообще прилетел ли. Единственное, что их связывает - это количество. Закон сохранения массы, куда деваться...

Comment: что-то сделал, но наверняка неправильно, выбрасывает исключение

Comment: А ты аэропорт-то сделал? то, во что самолёты вываливают пассажиров, и откуда их забирают автобусы?

Comment: нет, я всех пассажиров в один список поставил, и его передавал всем автобусам

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем нужен лок на уровне автобуса.  Также условия 100% загрузки автобуса и того, что семьи могут ехать только в одном и том же автобусе, для случайно сгенерированных данных выглядят слишком блокирующими (какой-нибудь автобус/семья может никогда не уехать из аэропорта).

Comment: Интересная задачка, попробую сам решить

Comment: и что получилось?

Comment: Я с немного другими условиями эту задачу сделал. Что касается вашего кода, попробуйте использовать landingOnBus как synchronized. Вы 14 раз передаёте классу Handler список самолётов (Не кажется ли это вам некрасивым ? ) так же коллекцию planes следует пометить как volatile. т.к непонятно, какой монитор какое значение держит на руках. метод join тут тоже не нужен. Зачем одному автобусу ждать другой ? Пассажиров забрал и вперед.

Comment: Ихмо, должна быть одна общая для всех, коллекция самолётов, и 14 потоков - автобусов. У вас 14 автобусов и 14 списков которые ссылаются на 1 список, который к тому же ещё и локальный. Попробуйте сделать не автобус отдельным потоком, а скажем автобусную станцию, которая будет сама направлять автобусы в цикле.

Comment: то есть в классе BusStation мне нужно два значения список самолетов и микроавтобусов, тогда в методе landingOnBus делать цикл самолетов и микроавтобусов? Как их тогда запускать?

Comment: Унаследовать Bus от Thread и запускать. У вас будет 1 главный поток Busstation который запускает другие потоки Bus. Каждый Bus в своём потоке хватает монитор BusStation у которого есть ссылка на самолёты, и пытается забрать оттуда пассажиров. Чтобы не держать весь лист заблокированным, можно по индексу отдавать нескольким автобусам только 1 самолёт.  Я бы так сделал

Comment: если не трудно можете написать код, потому что что-то не очень понимаю как

Comment: написать как оно должно выглядеть

Comment: B BusStation запускать циклом Bus, а в Bus тогда в методе run разделять семьи в микроавтобусы и удалять их из самолета?